# How can I build/concatenate strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, conventions

Does JavaScript support substitution/interpolation?

#### Overview

---

I'm working on a JavaScript project, and as it's getting bigger, keeping strings in good shape is getting a lot harder. I'm wondering what's the easiest and most conventional way to construct or build strings in JavaScript.

My experience so far:

> String concatenation starts looking ugly and becomes harder to maintain as the project becomes more complex.

The most important this at this point is succinctness and readability, think a bunch of moving parts, not just 2-3 variables.

It's also important that it's supported by major browsers as of today (i.e., at least [ES5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2009) supported).

I'm aware of the JavaScript concatenation shorthand:

```
var x = 'Hello';
var y = 'world';
console.log(x + ', ' + y);
```

And of the [String.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) function.

I'm looking for something a bit neater.

Ruby and Swift do it in an interesting way.

**Ruby**

```
var x = 'Hello'
var y = 'world'
print "#{x}, #{y}"
```

**Swift**

```
var x = "Hello"
var y = "world"
println("\(x), \(y)")
```

I was thinking that there might be something like that in JavaScript maybe something similar to [sprintf.js](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js).

#### Question

---

Can this be done without a third-party library? If not, what can I use?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

With ES6, you can use

- [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

  ```
  var username = 'craig';
  console.log(`hello ${username}`);
  ```

ES5 and below:

- use the `+` operator

  ```
  var username = 'craig';
  var joined = 'hello ' + username;
  ```
- String's [`concat(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)

  ```
  var username = 'craig';
  var joined = 'hello '.concat(username);
  ```

Alternatively, use Array methods:

- [`join(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

  ```
  var username = 'craig';
  var joined = ['hello', username].join(' ');
  ```
- Or even fancier, [`reduce(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) combined with any of the above:

  ```
  var a = ['hello', 'world', 'and', 'the', 'milky', 'way'];
  var b = a.reduce(function(pre, next) {
    return pre + ' ' + next;
  });
  console.log(b); // hello world and the milky way
  ```

Comment: With ES6 Template strings, pay attention to use the back-ticks (``) rather than '' or "" (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings?hl=en)

Comment: This answer doesn't suggest "a best". So for me, first two are very fast and readable, to decide I checked how big companies do it and  I leaned for _Template literals_ https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#es6-template-literals

Answer (score 27):

I'm disappointed that nobody in the other answers interpreted "best way" as "fastest way"...

I pulled the 2 examples from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-fast-string-concatenation) and added `str.join()` and `str.reduce()` from [nishanths's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31845980/1599699) above. Here are my results on Firefox 77.0.1 on Linux.

---

**Note:** I discovered while testing these that if I place `str = str.concat()` and `str +=` directly before or after each other, the second one always performs a fair bit better... So I ran these tests individually and commented the others out for the results...

**Even still**, they varied **widely** in speed if I reran them, so I measured 3 times for each.

1 character at a time:

- `str = str.concat()`: `841, 439, 956 ms / 1e7 concat()'s`
- `............str +=`: `949, 1130, 664 ms / 1e7 +='s`
- `.........[].join()`: `3350, 2911, 3522 ms / 1e7 characters in []`
- `.......[].reduce()`: `3954, 4228, 4547 ms / 1e7 characters in []`

26 character string at a time:

- `str = str.concat()`: `444, 744, 479 ms / 1e7 concat()'s`
- `............str +=`: `1037, 473, 875 ms / 1e7 +='s`
- `.........[].join()`: `2693, 3394, 3457 ms / 1e7 strings in []`
- `.......[].reduce()`: `2782, 2770, 4520 ms / 1e7 strings in []`

---

So, regardless of whether appending 1 character at a time or a string of 26 at a time:

- **Clear winner: basically a tie between `str = str.concat()` and `str +=`**
- **Clear loser: `[].reduce()`, followed by `[].join()`**

---

My code, easy to run in a browser console:

```js
{
  console.clear();

  let concatMe = 'a';
  //let concatMe = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

  //[].join()
  {
    s = performance.now();
    let str = '', sArr = [];
    for (let i = 1e7; i > 0; --i) {
      sArr[i] = concatMe;
    }
    str = sArr.join('');
    e = performance.now();
    console.log(e - s);
    console.log('[].join(): ' + str);
  }

  //str +=
  {
    s = performance.now();
    let str = '';
    for (let i = 1e7; i > 0; --i) {
      str += concatMe;
    }
    e = performance.now();
    console.log(e - s);
    console.log('str +=: ' + str);
  }

  //[].reduce()
  {
    s = performance.now();
    let str = '', sArr = [];
    for (let i = 1e7; i > 0; --i) {
      sArr[i] = concatMe;
    }
    str = sArr.reduce(function(pre, next) {
      return pre + next;
    });
    e = performance.now();
    console.log(e - s);
    console.log('[].reduce(): ' + str);
  }

  //str = str.concat()
  {
    s = performance.now();
    let str = '';
    for (let i = 1e7; i > 0; --i) {
      str = str.concat(concatMe);
    }
    e = performance.now();
    console.log(e - s);
    console.log('str = str.concat(): ' + str);
  }

  'Done';
}
```

Comment: I'm getting similar results. `''.concat(...strings)` is consistently outperforming all other methods. I wonder why it is not getting the love it deserves.

Answer (score 10):

```
var descriptor = 'awesome';
console.log(`ES6 is ${descriptor}!`);
```

More: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings?hl=en

Comment: I wish this works would have been great!, but it's only supported in chrome at the moment :L
Great answer though :)

Comment: And Firefox, and Opera. :) Just not IE or Safari.

Comment: As of right now (March 2020) ES6 is supported in all major browsers, so you're free to use it *except* if you need to support old, outdated, terrible browsers (in other words, Internet Explorer)

Answer (score 8):

I think **replace()** deserves mentioning here.

During some conditions, the replace method can serve you well when building strings. Specifically, obviously, when your injecting a dynamic part into an otherwise static string. Example:

```
var s = 'I am {0} today!';
var result = s.replace('{0}', 'hungry');
// result: 'I am hungry today!'
```

The placeholder which to replace can obviously be anything. I use "{0}", "{1}" etc out of habit from C#. It just needs to be unique enough not to occur in the string other than where intended.

So, provided we can fiddle with the string parts a bit, OPs example could be solved like this too:

```
var x = 'Hello {0}';
var y = 'World';
var result = x.replace('{0}', y);
// result: 'Hello World'. -Oh the magic of computing!
```

Reference for "replace":
https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `concat` function.

```
var hello = "Hello ";
var world = "world!";
var res = hello.concat(world);
```

Comment: If I wanted to build a much longer string say with 6 different moving parts, it wouldn't be readable at all with the concat function.

Comment: If `hello` didn't have the trailing space, how would you achieve it all in the same line? `hello.concat(world.concat(' '));`? Or would you still use the shorthand and do `hello.concat(' ' + world)`?

Comment: @MrHaze `concat` takes a variable number of arguments. So, perhaps, `str1.concat.apply(null, [str2, str3, str4])` slightly improves readability?

Comment: str1.concat.apply(null, [str2, str3, str4])     <-- how does the performance of this compare to using [...].join('')?

Comment: @MikeStoddart im probably way way way late on answering this one, but as the other answer on this post says, [...].join and .reduce are both very slow for string concatination compared to .concat however i would add that the new ES6 way with string interpolation (`hello there ${name}`) is much much more cleaner and also very performant

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/), it's made to make javascript code more concise.. For string concatenation, you could do something like this:

```
first_name = "Marty"
full_name = "#{first_name} McFly"
console.log full_name
```

Maybe you can start [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-absolute-beginners-guide-to-coffeescript) to see what's offered by coffescript..