# How do I add a variable content into URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think it must be easy, but still, can not figure out how to solve this.
So I've got a variable that contains a URL:

```
> var siteurl = 'http://my-site.com';
```

All I need is to add "siteurl" variable into another url before **/load.php**

```
function load(){
    $.getJSON('/load.php', function(data) {
        appendComments(data);
    });
}
```

So that the ultimate url was

> http://my-site.com/load.php

Comment: siteurl + '/load.php'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to do string building/concatenation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845895/whats-the-best-way-to-do-string-building-concatenation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge a string variable with another string using `+`

```
function load(){
    var siteurl = 'http://my-site.com';
    var url = siteurl + '/load.php';
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        appendComments(data);
    });
}
```