# Angular 2 _this is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I'm getting an error in the function call below saying that this.albumDetails is undefined for a specific line even though all other this calls are working fine.

the error is: TypeError: _this.albumDetails is undefined

The error probably occurs at this.albumDetails.concat(items) where items is an array of json objects

Any assistance is appreciated thanks.

```js
export class AppComponent {
albums: any[];
albumDetails: any[];
searchAlbum(input: any){
    this.show = true;
    this.searchService.getAlbum(input).subscribe(data => {
      this.albums = data;
      for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        this.searchService.getDetails(this.albums[i].artist, this.albums[i].name, this.albums[i].mbid).subscribe(items => {
          this.albumDetails = this.albumDetails.concat(items); //Error occuring here at this.albumDetails.concat(items)
          console.log(this.albumDetails);
        });
      }
    });
  }
 }
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `this.albumDetails`?

Comment: Outside the function in the class that searchAlbum is defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the `albumDetails` to empty string

```
albumDetails : string =' '
```

Alternatively you can use ES5 syntax for string concatenation as

```
this.albumDetails = `${this.albumDetails}${items}`;
```

Using backtick

```
` `
```

[Reference Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845895/whats-the-best-way-to-do-string-building-concatenation-in-javascript)

**Update 1 : As per comment**

It seems that `albumDetails` is an array, so an array has to be initialized before pushing elements, so add the below line out of the for loop

```
this.albumDetails = [];
```

or during the variable declaration

```
albumDetails = [];
```

Comment: Damn maybe i'm using the wrong function here, i'm trying to push an array from a json call to albumDetails so that i have an array of arrays. I should probably use .push here instead of .concat, but I still get the undefined error nonetheless

Comment: `albumDetails` is an array or a string?? can you add the complete post

Comment: sorry I assumed that it would be clear that an array was already initialized, i have updated the code in the question.

Comment: @WilliamLake. updated answer should work. is it working or need more help?