# String literal first or second in concatenation?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, is there any circumstance where there is a semantic difference between these two options?

```
foo.bar + ''
```

...and...

```
'' + foo.bar
```

I would've expected the latter to more reliably coerce the result to a string, but I can't find any discussion of this (after much Googling) nor any example where it seems to matter.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845895/whats-the-best-way-to-do-string-building-concatenation-in-javascript

Comment: Isn't the most readable way to do string coercion `String(foo.bar)`?

Comment: @Neil Yes, it is, there is however a semantic difference in that the global `String` variable could be overwritten.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**They are the same** as others have already mentioned, with additional considerations listed by [**@Zohaib Ijaz**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51564496/10079674):

```js
var values = [
  undefined,
  null,
  false,
  true,
  0,
  -1,
  1,
  NaN,
  Infinity,
  '',
  '123',
  'abc123',
  '123abc',
  [],
  [0],
  [1],
  {},
  {a: 1},
  function(){}   
];
var foo = {bar: null};

values.forEach(function(value) {
  foo.bar = value;
  
  console.log("foo.bar + '':", foo.bar + '');
  console.log("'' + foo.bar:", '' + foo.bar);
});
```

However **there are significant differences**, when you have **more than 2 operands** as mentioned by [**@ibrahim mahrir**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51564637/10079674):

```js
var values = [
  undefined,
  null,
  false,
  true,
  0,
  -1,
  1,
  NaN,
  Infinity,
  '',
  '123',
  'abc123',
  '123abc',
  [],
  [0],
  [1],
  {},
  {a: 1},
  function(){}   
];
var foo = {bar: null};

values.forEach(function(value) {
  foo.bar = value;
  
  console.log("foo.bar + '' + foo.bar:", foo.bar + '' + foo.bar);
  console.log("'' + foo.bar + '':", '' + foo.bar + '');
});
```

Comment: Well of course there's a difference between `foo.bar + '' + foo.bar` and `'' + foo.bar + ''`. Expecting those to be the same would be like expecting `1 + 2 + 1` and `2 + 1 + 2` to be the same. ibrahim's example is a bit subtler.

Answer (score 16):

Both are the same.

There is only a difference if there are other `+` (on the left or the right). In other words:

```
1 + 1 + ''                          // results in '2'
```

Is not the same as:

```
'' + 1 + 1                          // results in '11'
```

Comment: To be fair, this does not match the OP's `foo.bar + ''` versus `'' + foo.bar` comparison.

Comment: @trincot That is already answered by _"Both are the same"_. I just wanted to include this related example that could produce a difference. After all, we don't know how OP is using this exactly.

Comment: @trincot ... It might as well be `something + foo.bar + ''` or `'' + foo.bar + something`

Comment: Yes, I agree. Precedence rules (left to right) will make the left side not `foo.bar` at the moment of the addition the OP is looking at. But I can see that it would be interesting if the OP is not actually looking for that precise case only.

Answer (score 5):

If one of the operands is a string, `valueOf()` or  `toString()` will be called on the other one, so yes they are exactly the same.

12.8.3 of the spec:

> ```
>  AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression
> ```
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let lval be ? GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let rval be ? GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lprim be ? ToPrimitive(lval).
> 6. Let rprim be ? ToPrimitive(rval).
> 7. **If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String,** then
>
>    a. Let lstr be ? ToString(lprim).
>
>    b. Let rstr be ? ToString(rprim).
>
>    c. Return the String that is the result of concatenating lstr and rstr

Comment: This is not entirely true: before `toString` is called on the non-string argument, the `ToPrimitive` step is executed which may involve a call to `valueOf`, and if that result is a primitive, `toString` is never called (not to be confused with `ToString` in the reference which is about converting one primitive type to another, which does not involve a call to `toString`).

Comment: @trincot yup, clarified that

Answer (score 3):

Here are few rules taken from [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/)

- If at least one operand is an object, it is converted to a primitive value (string, number or boolean);
- After conversion, if at least one operand is string type, the second operand is converted to string and the concatenation is executed;
- In other case both operands are converted to numbers and arithmetic addition is executed.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference.

If `foo.bar` is not a primitive value then first `valueOf` is called on it. If that still does not return a primitive value, `toString` is called on it. If that still does not return a primitive value, an error is triggered.

In all this, the `foo.bar` object is not aware in which context `valueOf` or `toString` are called. There is no way the object can differentiate between the two cases you mention. It does not even have to be one of those two.

Finally, there is no way to set a trap on the `+` operator, so you could know its operands.

Here is a demo of how `valueOf` and `toString` are called in that order:

```js
const foo = { 
    bar: {
        valueOf() {
            console.log('valueOf');
            return this; // not a primitive value, so now toString will be called.
        },
        toString() {
            console.log('toString');
            return "1";
        }
    }
}

console.log(foo.bar + '');
console.log("====");
console.log('' + foo.bar);
```