# looking to concatenate these into a single string with hyphen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am having mapping function like this below where i am assigning this object to searchable drop down list in other page

```
  const mapOptions =
equipmentDensitySourceTypeData !== (undefined && null)
  ? equipmentDensitySourceTypeData.libraryEquipment.map(code => ({
      label:
        code.equipmentSource.name -
        code.equipmentSource.edition -
        code.category -
        code.spaceFunction -
        code.revision,
      key: code.id,
    }))
  : null;
```

here only the revision is integer and remaining all are strings when i check `mapOptions` object i am getting `label` value as `NaN` and for key i am getting correct value ..

I am looking for label should be string separated by `-`

I am not sure where i am doing wrong with this one, Could any please suggest any idea on this.. I am using React JS with ES6 for the above code

PS : I also tried like this `${code.category}` - `${code.spaceFunction}` but getting same `NaN`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to do string building/concatenation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845895/whats-the-best-way-to-do-string-building-concatenation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to concate the string. Note the usage of back tick

```
const mapOptions =
  equipmentDensitySourceTypeData !== (undefined && null) ?
  equipmentDensitySourceTypeData.libraryEquipment.map(code => ({
    label: `${code.equipmentSource.name}-
            ${code.equipmentSource.edition}-
            ${code.category}-
            ${code.spaceFunction}-
            ${code.revision}`,
    key: code.id,
  })) :
  null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using -

```
const mapOptions =
equipmentDensitySourceTypeData && 
equipmentDensitySourceTypeData.libraryEquipment.map(code => ({
  label:
    `${code.equipmentSource.name} -
    ${code.equipmentSource.edition} -
    ${code.category} -
    ${code.spaceFunction} -
    ${code.revision}`,
  key: code.id,
}));
```