# Convert map out to a string

Tags: reactjs

I have below code

```
const DisplayData = filteredCardMemberData.map(
  (info) => (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key -- disabling eslint rule
    <div> {info.productDescription}</div>
  )
);
```

I gives the below output

```
Apple
Mango
```

I want to convert the output as

```
Apple, Mango
```

Also, I want "Apple, Mango" to be one string, all the data should be concatenated to only string and separated by comma(,).
Can you help me.

Comment: `<div>{filteredCardMemberData.join(', ')}</div>`

Comment: It is rendering output as below

[object Object], [object Object]

Comment: Hi, @Purva Parulekar try this [**Code sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hugle-z0tk89?file=/src/App.js) and also see my answer for better understanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build/concatenate strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845895/how-to-build-concatenate-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to use `.join()`.

Your final code look like:

```
const mainData = filteredCardMemberData.map((info) => info.productDescription);

const finalData = mainData.join(', ');

return <div>{finalData}</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const DisplayData = filteredCardMemberData.map(
  (info) => (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key -- disabling eslint rule
    <div> {info.productDescription}</div>
  )
).join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join method for this

```
const DisplayData = filteredCardMemberData.map(
  (info) => (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key -- disabling eslint rule
    <div> {info.productDescription}</div>
  ).join(',')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct then you are using ReactJS. Consider using React's `useMemo` hook to memorize the result if the data is expensive to compute or frequently changes:

```js
import {useMemo} from 'react'

const finalData = useMemo(() => {
  const mainData = filteredCardMemberData.map(
    ({productDescription}) => productDescription   // you can also access the value like this productDescription.value
  )
  return mainData.join(', ')
}, [filteredCardMemberData])
```

This will only recompute the data if the dependency array (in this case, `filteredCardMemberData`) changes. Here is some other info which I think you need to read: [**efficient way-to-concatenate-strings**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696632/most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-javascript)

Here is Demo:- [**CodeSandBox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hugle-z0tk89?file=/src/App.js)